# Business Objects: Comparing Rows

Tags: mysql, business-objects

I have a file containing several rows of data.  The column called 'Description' contains data that is always duplicated and is in alphabetical order so the matching rows are always together.  Data can be in 4s, 6s etc, but, always an even number of rows (see row 20 to 23).

I need to create a record count (number of records that match) and a movement count (number of movements for each record count).  The language in Excel is easy (see diagram), but I'm not sure how to replicate it using Business Objects.

I've tried using 'Previous()', so:

```
=If([Description]=Previous([Description])) Then~
```

But whatever I try after 'Then' only seems to create a circular reference error because I keep trying to increase the variable by one.

Hope that all makes sense.

Can anyone help, especially with column W.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II2mX.jpg)

Comment: Please include the data in the post rather than an image.  People who want to help you will have an easier time copying the data from this question than having to manually enter the values from the image.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Column "Movements" you can create the fowling function and the SELECT

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION rownr (s CHAR(64))
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    IF s = @rownr_oldval THEN
      SET @rownr_nr:=@rownr_nr+1;
    ELSE
      SET @rownr_nr:=1;
    END IF;

    SET @rownr_oldval:=s;
    RETURN @rownr_nr;
END //
DELIMITER ;


SELECT
 rownr(Description) AS Movements,
 m.*
FROM mytable m,
 (SELECT rownr('')) AS tmp
ORDER BY Description;
```

Comment: Thank you Bernd, I'll give that a go.